# Integrating SugarCRM with Microsoft Exchange Server

Tags: sugarcrm

What I need is a connector for integrating SugarCRM with Microsoft Exchange server.
I am using SugarCRM CE 6.0.2

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? Google has many results for integrating SugarCRM + MS Exchange http://www.google.com/search?q=sugarcrm+microsoft+exchange

Comment: @moontear I've already had a look at http://www.accelerate4.com/pdf/SugarCRMtoMicrosoftExchange.pdf and wanted to know if there was maybe another way of achieving the Outlook integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions of integrating/synchronizing SugarCRM with Microsoft Exchange Server.

The first one as you pointed out is using the open source implementation of Microsoft Exchange Server's protocols from [OpenChange](http://www.openchange.com). A complete tutorial is posted at the [accelerate4.com](http://www.accelerate4.com/pdf/SugarCRMtoMicrosoftExchange.pdf) site you mentioned above.

The [official SugarCRM](https://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/resources/webcast/OutlookCRM) go-to way is using a Riva Integration Server. However there are several applications/plug-ins for synchronizing available: [J-ExSync](http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/j-exsync), [ZuckerExchange](http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/zuckerexchange), whereas I don't know about their quality. You might want to search through the [application list on SugarForge](http://www.sugarforge.org/softwaremap/trove_list.php?form_cat=328).